# Segmentation fault in my program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My sorting program results in a "segmentation fault 11":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    // Asking user for number of inputs in an array
    int n;
    do {
        printf ("enter the number of intigers you want to sort\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }while (n<=1);

    int sort [n];
    printf ("please enter %d numbers\n",n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&sort[i]);
    }
    printf("you entered\n ");

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf(" %d ",sort[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int k,c,i,x;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
       if (sort[i]<sort[i-1]){
           k=i-2;
           while (sort[k]>sort[i]){
               k--;
           }
           k++;
           x =sort[i];
           c=i;
           for (c=i;c>k;c++){
              sort[c-1]=sort[c];
           }
           sort[k]=x;    
        }
    }
    printf ("Sorted numbers :-\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf ("%d ",sort[i]);
    }
     printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have looked up the internet and found that it is caused because a variable has value that exceeds the system's memory limit. But cannot understand that concept.

Comment: On which line does the fault occur?

Comment: what sorting algorithm is that?

Comment: Looks like a bubble sort.

Comment: Consider using a debugger.

Comment: actually, the seg fault 11 is caused by some pointer pointing outside the area that your specific program is allowed to access.  a typical cause would be a pointer that contains 0 (NULL).

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this line: `int k,c,i,x;`  1) variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).  2) for ease of documentation, understanding, debugging, etc, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 3):

```
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      if (sort[i]<sort[i-1])
```

You are accessing array out of its bounds.Maybe you want to start your loop from `1`.Also

```
   k=i-2;
   while (sort[k]>sort[i])
```

will access index beyond `0` for example if `i` is `0` or `1` or `2`

Answer (score 3):

1. `k = i - 2;` looks unstable for low values of `i`.
2. `sort[i - 1]` is *undefined* when `i` is zero.

The thing causes the behaviour of `sort[k]` to be *undefined*.

Moral of the story: check all the array indexes before attempting to retrieve an array element. Your debugger will help you here.

Comment: I think `k` is initialized on all control paths.Can you please elaborate more on this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all said before:

```
       c=i;
       for (c=i;c>k;c++){
          sort[c-1]=sort[c];
       }
       sort[k]=x;
```

1. `i` can be `0` -> `c` can be `0` -> `sort[c-1]` would also result in accessing array out of bounds.
2. There is no need to initialize `c=i` twice. It is enough to do it in the loop-declaration